# How can I extract the name and value of an array of objects?

Tags: c#

The code below renders the name and value of each item in an array. Is it possible to extract the names (today, tomorrow) as strings? Like in the pseudo code below? Ideally I could pass in the variables as a simple array.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var today = DateTime.Today;
    var tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
    Log(new { today }, new { tomorrow });

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static void Log(params object[] fields)
{
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(field);
    }
}

/* OUTPUT
{ today = 10/10/2019 00:00:00 }
{ tomorrow = 11/10/2019 00:00:00 }
*/
```

## PSEUDO CODE

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var today = DateTime.Today;
    var tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
    Log(today, tomorrow);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static void Log(params object[] fields)
{
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(field.Name);   
        Console.WriteLine(field.Value);

    }
}
/*
Desired output

today
10/10/2019 00:00:00
tomorrow
11/10/2019 00:00:00
*/
```

EDIT

So I've created a struct:

```
    public struct LogValue
    {
        public static LogValue Create(string name, object value)
        {
           return new LogValue(name, value);
        }

        private LogValue(string name, object value)
        {
            Name = name;
            Value = value;
        }

        public string Name { get; }
        public object Value { get; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Name}: {Value}";
        }
    }
```

I can now do this:

```
Log( LogValue.Create(nameof(today), today), LogValue.Create(nameof(tomorrow), tomorrow));
```

Any ideas for making it less verbose?

Comment: You can't : `nameof(field)` = "field" and `field.Value` is the `field` value. You can pass strings to the method like ("name1", value1, "name2", value2...) or tuples to be sure to have count matching or everything like a dictionary or a list of class or struct.

Comment: `new { today }` and `new { tomorrow }` isn't really a good way to do things because this causes the compiler to generate two classes for you at compile time, one with a property named `today`, and one with a property named `tomorrow`. Each item you add generates another class. I'd instead recommend using a data structure that maintains Name vs Value.

Comment: @John good points, I removed my comment before even posting :)

Comment: I have been using ```new KeyValuePair<string, object>("today", today)``` but it's a bit verbose and tuples are not much better ```Tuple.Create<string, object>("today", today)```

Answer (score 0):

As Olivier Rogier already said: you can't.

What you can do is something like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> toLog = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    toLog.Add("today", DateTime.Today);
    toLog.Add("tomorrow", DateTime.Today.AddDays(1));
    Log(toLog );

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static void Log(Dictionary<string, object> toLog)
{
    foreach (var kvp in toLog)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key);   
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, let's first understand what your code is doing:

- `new { today }` is shorthand for `new { today = today }`.
- The `new { }` syntax will create an anonymous type to hold this data. Basically you are creating two classes here, one with a "today" property, and one with a "tomorrow" property.

See [anonymous types documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) for more information.

**I would advise against doing it this way, and instead use a dictionary, a list of KeyValuePair, or some other data structure that holds the data how you want it.**

Anyway, since these are single-property classes, you could retrieve the property something like this:

```
var properties = field.GetType().GetProperties();
if (properties.Count() == 1)
{
    var property = properties.Single();
    Console.WriteLine(property.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(property.GetValue(field));
}
```

I strongly recommend something like Thomas Voß's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58324498/3181933) instead of doing this.

If you were you were to use a dictionary, you could use `nameof` with your variables:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
var myValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
myValues[nameof(today)] = today;
myValues[nameof(tomorrow)] = tomorrow;
myValues["test"] = "hello";

foreach (var field in myValues)
{
    Console.WriteLine(field.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(field.Value);
}
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lmlfYY)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which version of `C#` or `.NET` you're using, but if `KeyValuePair<string, object>` and `Tuple<string, object>` are too verbose for you then you could try `ValueTuple` as long as you're on `C#` 7.

```csharp
public void Main()
{
   Log(("today", DateTime.Today), ("tomorrow", DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)));
}

public void Log(params (string Name, object Value)[] values)
{
   foreach (var value in values)
   {
      Console.WriteLine($"{value.Name} => {value.Value}");
   }
}
```